# Why wont these chars show when reversing string?

Tags: string, go, reverse

I'm just wondering why these asian characters in this string wont show up when I reverse and print the individual characters in the string.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

        a := "The quick brown 狐 jumped over the lazy 犬"
        var lenght int = len(a) - 1

        for ; lenght > -1; lenght-- {

                 fmt.Printf("%c", a[lenght])
        }
        fmt.Println()
}
```

Comment: Multibyte characters.

Comment: @MattBall are you sure? I think go uses strings which are made up of runes.

Comment: @EricUrban I'm not especially familiar with Go, but I'm pretty sure that is the problem. [Indexing a string accesses individual bytes, not characters.](http://blog.golang.org/strings)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are accessing the string array by byte not by 'logical character'
To better understand this example breaks the string first as an array of runes and then prints the rune backwards.

http://play.golang.org/p/bzbo7k6WZT

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    msg := "The quick brown 狐 jumped over the lazy 犬"

    elements := make([]rune, 0)

    for _, rune := range msg {
        elements = append(elements, rune)
    }

    for i := len(elements) - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        fmt.Println(string(elements[i]))
    }
}
```

Shorter Version: http://play.golang.org/p/PYsduB4Rgq

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    msg := "The quick brown 狐 jumped over the lazy 犬"

    elements := []rune(msg)

    for i := len(elements) - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        fmt.Println(string(elements[i]))
    }
}
```